# Google cloud data fusion conection to informix

Tags: google-cloud-platform, driver, informix, fusion

I am setting a pipeline to extract data from informix(IBM) database to Google Bigquery, I have added driver for informix jdbc-4.50.4.1.jar(https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.informix/jdbc/4.50.4.1), but when test conection from componet it is ok, but when preview or deploy pipeline appear next error

Error deploy pipeline

[image: Error deploy pipeline]

I have tried differents skins but have the same error, also I have connected to informix from my local client DBeaver with the same driver and settings and this works well

What setting I can change, I am attentive waitting responses.

Comment: You will have to do some more digging. The error "Transactions not supported. Please check the system logs for more details". This could be that the Informix database you are pointing to is unlogged and thus doesn't support transactions. You could check that. Otherwise I would go looking for these extra logs to see if you can get the JDBC stack trace or SQLException message of what went wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Finally had the conection, the problem was in how was created the databases, there are confict with the dbspace and chunk  and the logging mode, I did a test with new database with log registered ( WITH LOG) and I didn't have problems